Index on multiple fields, field order relevant?
When you create an index on multiple fields
(like in  create unique index r_at1_aspect_budget on br_at1(aspect_id, budget_id)
is the order of the fields relevant?  Should it be ordered by selectivity ?
Is the order of the WHERE clauses relevant in a query? (or is this all overruled by the optimizer)

An index on columns (A, B) can be used for WHERE A = 1 or for WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2, but it cannot be used for WHERE B = 2.
The same index can be used for ORDER BY A or for ORDER BY A, B, but it cannot be used for ORDER BY B.
Please note that some indexes can be created by the database itself. In H2 a primary key or unique constraint always creates a unique index on its columns if a compatible index doesn't exist yet. A referential constraint always creates a non-unique index on referencing columns if a compatible index doesn't exist.

Thanks.
Can you also say something about field order and selectivity when creating the index?

Everything depends on your actual queries if you want to speed up some of them with this index, because different queries may need different indexes. If you need this index only for uniqueness check, this check is not affected by order of columns.
